# How to save data on indexedDB and retreive it on another page which will be displayed in table format?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a time management app so when a schedule is made, all the things the person has created will now be shown in table format on another page which will serve as the history... How can I go about it, using Javascript no server side script.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your life easy, DO NOT use indexDB. just use localStorage. It will do everything you want it to do with no hassle and no complicated code.

For example:

```
var userTable = [{id: 1, name: 'Bill'}, {id: 2, name: 'Jim'}];
localStorage.userTable = JSON.stringify(userTable);
```

then to retrieve:

```
var userTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.userTable);
```